# Executed program in process return the same value

Tags: c, process

My program should read a user id and password, creates a new process to run the VALIDATE program (which is in file validate.c), sends to VALIDATE program the user id and password, and prints a message "Password verified" if the user id and password matched or either "Invalid password" or "No such user" depending on the return value of the validate program.

My code does almost everything but I do not know how to implement last part about printing a message "Password verified" if the user id and password matched or either "Invalid password" or "No such user" depending on the return value of the validate program…. It always prints me PASSWORD VERIFIED even if it is not….. Any help will appreciated. Sorry if it is too simple question….I am beginner in C. Any help will be appreciated….thanks….

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/wait.h>
    #define MAXLINE 256
    #define MAXPASSWD 10

    void strip( char *str, int capacity ) {
        char *ptr;
        if ( ( ptr = strchr( str, '\n' ) ) == NULL ) {
            str[capacity - 1] = '\0';
        }
        else {
            *ptr = '\0';
        }
    }


    int main( void ) {
        char userid[MAXLINE];
        char password[MAXLINE];
        pid_t pid;
        int fd[2];
        /* Read a user id and password from stdin */
        printf( "User id:\n" );
        if ( ( fgets( userid, MAXLINE, stdin ) ) == NULL ) {
            fprintf( stderr, "Could not read from stdin\n" );
            exit( 1 );
        }
        strip( userid, MAXPASSWD );
        strip( userid, MAXPASSWD );

        printf( "Password:\n" );
        if ( ( fgets( password, MAXLINE, stdin ) ) == NULL ) {
            fprintf( stderr, "Could not read from stdin\n" );
            exit( 1 );
        }
        strip( password, MAXPASSWD );
        pipe( fd );
        pid = fork( );
        if ( pid == -1 ){
            printf( "Error making process\n" );
            return ( -1 );
        }
        if (pid==0){
                close(fd[0]);
                printf("Hey I am the child with pid: %d\n",getpid());
                execl("/h/u15/c2/00/c2rsaldi/csc209labs/ex5/validate.c","validate.c", NULL);           

     }    
    /*Your code here*/
   int status;   

    if (pid>0){
              close(fd[1]);
               write(fd[1],password,(strlen(password)-1));
               write(fd[1],userid,(strlen(userid)-1));
         if (waitpid(pid,&status,0)==0){
            if (WIFEXITED(status) && !WEXITSTATUS(status)){
                      if (WEXITSTATUS(status)==3){
                                 printf(" No such a user\n");
    }  else if (WEXITSTATUS(status)==2){
                                printf("Invalid password");
    }else
                                 printf("Password verified\n");
}

}

}




return 0;
}
```

Comment: What value do you get in status ?

Comment: status is the value which i get from validate program right?! how to check it?! i even did not check the return value of the status….

Comment: You use ` && WEXITSTATUS(status)` in one branch, but was it ever your intention to use ` && !WEXITSTATUS(status)` for any other?

Comment: Why do you `exec` a `.c` file and not the executable? Why do you `write` the username password without their last characters, and not separated? Is an exit status of `0` a "verified" or "failed" condition?

Comment: Why do you not `close()` the pipe ends you are not using in both the child and parent, and why does the parent not `close()` the write end of the pipe once it's done `write()`'ing the username and password?

Comment: Assuming that an exit code of `1` means "password verified", be aware that `WIFEXITED( status ) && WEXITSTATUS( status )` captures _all_ cases where the process exited and where the process returned a _nonzero_ exit code. Thus your code can never reach the places where an explicit check is made for a specific value, much less a specific non-zero one. In effect you wrote `WIFEXITED( status ) && WEXITSTATUS( status ) != 0`; I suggest you write `WIFEXITED( status ) && WEXITSTATUS( status ) == 1` if that is what you intended.

Comment: How to check the value in status ? Very difficult task. Maybe with printf ?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot know what exactly your `Validate.c` has in it, therefore cannot know much about whether your conditions are all right. But I know this:

```
...
    if ( WIFEXITED( status ) && WEXITSTATUS( status ) ){
        //statements1
        printf( "Password verified\n" );
    }
    else if ( WIFEXITED( status ) && WEXITSTATUS( status ) ){
        //statements2
        if ( WEXITSTATUS( status ) == 3 ){
            printf( " No such a user\n" );
        }
        else if ( WIFEXITED( status ) && WEXITSTATUS( status ) ){
            if ( WEXITSTATUS( status ) == 2 ){
                printf( "Invalid password" );
            }
        }
    }
...
```

Here, you are telling your computer to execute the block I labelled as `statements1` if both the `WIFEXITED( status )` and `WEXITSTATUS( status )` are something non-zero, meaning *true*. Otherwise, meaning that either one of those two ***are*** zero, you ask your computer to check those two again, and execute the block I labelled as `statements2` if both are non-zero.

The `statements2` block may never get executed, because it is to be executed under the condition that a condition is first false, and then somehow suddenly true.

Unless there are other mistakes, removing that `if ( WIFEXITED( status ) && WEXITSTATUS( status ) )` right after that first `else` should fix your issue. You can also bring it into the following form, which would be equivalent:

```
...
    if ( WIFEXITED( status ) && WEXITSTATUS( status ) ){
        printf( "Password verified\n" );
    }
    else if ( WEXITSTATUS( status ) == 3 ){
        printf( " No such a user\n" );
    }
    else if ( WIFEXITED( status ) && WEXITSTATUS( status ) ){
        if ( WEXITSTATUS( status ) == 2 ){
            printf( "Invalid password" );
        }
    }
...
```

Well, there, another problem... The contents of the second `else if` may never be accessed, due to same reason. You probably have to remove that `if ( WIFEXITED( status ) && WEXITSTATUS( status ) )` as well. Equivalently:

```
...
    if ( WIFEXITED( status ) && WEXITSTATUS( status ) ){
        printf( "Password verified\n" );
    }
    else if ( WEXITSTATUS( status ) == 3 ){
        printf( " No such a user\n" );
    }
    else if ( WEXITSTATUS( status ) == 2 ){
        printf( "Invalid password" );
    }
...
```

*Disclaimer: These are all correct, only if both `WIFEXITED` and `WEXITSTATUS` don't have some global variables or something in themselves, causing them to return somehow different values each time they are called, despite having been called with identical arguments.*

Comment: status always 0  before WAIT condition in parent process!!! i think it does not go to "if(waitpid(pid,&status,0)==0)" condition… @ThoAppelsin

Comment: +1; But `WIFEXITED` and `WEXITSTATUS` are standardized POSIX macros, and they consistently return the 8 bit exit code from the 16-bit status. They are deterministic and pure. (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/wait.html)